# Why does $-\sum_x p(x) \log p(x) + \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(x,y) dy = \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(y \mid x) dy$?

Tags: calculus, probability, information-theory

If we write $p(\cdot)$ for a discrete probability function and $\mu(\cdot)$ for a continuous density function, then why does the following hold: $$-\sum_x p(x) \log p(x) + \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(x,y) dy = \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(y \mid x) dy$$

[Added for clarity]: $X$ is a discrete variable and $Y$ is a continuous variable, both are drawn from density function $μ(x,y)$. In other words, $p(x)=\int\mu(x,y)dy$ and $\mu(y)=\sum_x\mu(x,y)$.

I'm working through an information theory paper and stuck at this part. Thank you for your help and please let me know if there is anything I can do to clarify.

Comment: I think you are missing some information like: how does $p$ relate to $\mu$ and did you mean $\mu(x, .)$ is a continuous density for every $x$?

Comment: $X$ is a discrete variable and $Y$ is a continuous variable, both are drawn from density function $\mu(x,y)$. In other words, $p(x)=\int\mu(x,y)dy$ and $\mu(y)=\sum_x \mu(x,y)$.

Comment: This just follows from $\mu(y|x) =  \frac{\mu(x,y)}{p(x)}$.

Comment: Thanks, @Chester. I know that that is the basis of the equality, but I can't seem to get the entire process correct (I have an extra $p(x)$). Could you elaborate or write out your thought process in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(y \mid x) dy &= \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) ( \log \mu(x, y) -\log p(x) ) dy \\
&= \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(x, y) dy - \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log p(x) dy \\
&= \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(x, y) dy - \sum_x \log p(x) \int \mu(x,y) dy \\
&= \sum_x \int \mu(x,y) \log \mu(x, y) dy - \sum_x p(x)\log p(x) \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, @Chester. This was what I was looking for.